# document.getElementbyID returns NULL for the DIV with in iFrame

Tags: jquery, css, iframe

I have a JSP page which loads a static HTML page using iFrame. Now i am trying to change the alignment of one of the DIV (which is there in static HTML page) using the jQuery dynamically. But its not working.

```
var divEnbref = document.getElementById("enbref");
if(divEnbref!=''){
  $('#enbref').css("text-align" , "left");
}
```

DIV

```
<div id="enbref">Some Content</div>
```

Can someone help me.

Comment: Only a typo in the title. But why use it when you have jQuery loaded? And it would never be BLANK. Try `if($('#enbref').length>0){
  $('#enbref').css("text-align" , "left");
}`

Comment: The DIV for which i want to apply style is inside iFrame. Will this work?

Comment: Would like to add something. The static html is from different domain and able to get resource with out any error i.e. http code is 200. But when i try to access the document from iFrame ref i get error.

Comment: You cannot do what you want without a proxy. You may not change iframe content from a different origin

Answer (score 3):

As you are selecting element inside `iframe` you need to select the iframe first.

```
document.getElementById('myframe1').contentWindow.document.getElementById('enbref')
```

try this..

Comment: Thank You. I tired but i am getting Access Denied and Permission Dined when i  try to call var iFrameDoc = iFrame.contentDocument; or
var iFrameDoc = iFrame.contentWindow.document; Due to this iFrameDoc is undefined. IS there any other option?

Comment: Are you loading the iframe document from different domain ? or both parent and iframe are on same domain ?

Comment: iFrame content is from different domain.

Comment: You cannot control / Modify the content of Cross Origin iframes in all the browsers. chromes.

Answer (score 0):

use .innerHTML to get the content of your div

```
var divEnbref = document.getElementById("enbref").innerHTML;
```

then use condition statement

```
if(divEnbref!=''){
  $('#enbref').css("text-align" , "left");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var divEnbref = document.getElementById('enbref');

document.getElementById('enbref').style.textAlign = "right";
```

I've tried this in fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mgs4y3px/

May this will help you!